# Raspbian Lite: xinit at boot as soon as possible

Tags: raspbian, boot, xorg, systemd, raspbian-lite

Yes, another question on 'How to start the x server at boot' . I am new to linux admin things so I don't know how to do it correctly. I am using Raspbian Lite which does not include any graphical tools. I installed matchbox-window-manager and chromium-browser as well as the x11 utilities to launch a kiosk browser. At the moment I have to login to the console and then type `xinit startKiosk.sh` . The startKiosk.sh  file simply contains the matchbox-window-manager command, starts the chromium browser and sets some x options using `xset` .

Basically I just want Raspbian Lite to execute `xinit startKiosk.sh` **as soon as it is possible** on boot. (Maybe I would need to auto login. How do I do that?).

Although I could find some manuals on how to start the x server (with startx)  at boot or how to automatically log in (on arch linux), I could not find any tutorial that points out how to start xinit as soon as possible.

Is there a way of realizing this?

I would prefer systemd and I am using Raspbian Stretch Lite.

Comment: I tried creating a new service which ExecStarts the xinit and has DefaultDependencies=false . But it failed (according to systemctl status kiosk.service) because it "could not add a job dependency"

Comment: After disabling the 'Wait for network on boot' option in raspi-config and enabling auto login there as well and adding the xinit command into the '~/.profile' file, I have been able to start the x session after 10 seconds. However I would like to decrease the time. The last message that is shown for 2 seconds before autologin is something like 'Start waiting for plymouth to quit...up...' . Could I disable plymouth and decrease the boot time? I am not sure, but could I systemctl disable the most things (smbd, etc.)? Would they be loaded if they are queried?